# Adding custom fonts to sharepoint modern page

Tags: modern-pages, style

I'm currently trying to load GothamNarrow into the sharepoint modern page but am struggling to find a point where I can upload this font and use it.

Is this even possible using a modern sharepoint page?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [build an extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension) which include custom fonts as assets. Assets can be deployed to your [Office 365 CDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn)

This extension can be activated on any site collection: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpcustomaction?view=sharepoint-ps